# Rails 5 - Unable to Cleanse Test DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've recently started testing my app using `RSpec`. Being the testing noob that i am, i did not install the full suite of tools that people normally use (namely `FactoryGirl`, also now known as `FactoryBot`. And `DatabaseCleaner`).

Anyway here's what happened. After getting my feet wet with `RSpec`, i started using `FactoryBot` so that my tests looks less convoluted. Note that `:user` is a `Devise` object.

```
# spec/models/first_test_spec.rb

FactoryBot.create(:user) 
#Other Code
```

So i'm doing stuff with my `first_test_spec.rb` and i run it and everything is working perfectly fine. I then create my 2nd spec file

```
# spec/models/second_test_spec.rb

FactoryBot.create(:user)
#Other Code
```

Now here comes the problem. My tests are failing because `FactoryBot.create(:user)` is invalid, due to `Devise` requiring unique emails. Clearly this indicates that the data from my `first_test_spec` is persisting hence the error.

So i attempt to install `DatabaseCleaner` and hopefully clear my Test DB after each run. My `rails_helper` looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'

# Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

I think i've got everything set up correctly, so i'm uncertain if the errors are still occurring due to my `DatabaseCleaner` being set up wrongly.

Anyway, running `rspec` still throws the same error, where `second_test_spec` cannot create the `user` object because the email already exists (a validation that comes with Devise itself).

I then proceed to run the following:

```
rake db:test:prepare
rspec spec/models/second_test_spec.rb
```

And it still throws the same error. So right now, i have no idea if my database is being cleanse after running rspec. But i'm quite certain that i have been unable to purge my test database.

So i guess i really have 2 questions/problems:

1) How do you purge your test database? (Googling reveals that `rake db:test:prepare` is the way)

2) Is my `DatabaseCleaner` setup correctly? If so, shouldn't it be purging the database?

UPDATE:
As suggested to me in the comments, using `sequence` for creating unique fields with FactoryBot is recommended. Obviously that made the problem go away because there would no longer be validation errors from Devise.

I then went on to test a couple of things.

1. `rails c test`
   I ran this to check my test database and it was indeed empty. This indicates that DatabaseCleaner is working perfectly fine. What i fail to understand then, is why the need to sequence my email creation in FactoryBot? Or i suppose, i fail to understand how does RSpec "compile & run".
2. `puts @user.email`
   So i wanted to print out the emails to look at the sequencing to see if i'm able to decipher the problem. Here's what happens:

running `rspec spec/models/first_test_spec.rb`
Tutor email yields the number 2.

running `rspec spec/models/second_test_spec.rb`
Tutor email yields the number 3.

running `rspec`
Tutor email yields the numbers 2 & 5.

So i'm not sure if there are "problems" with my test suite. Clearly my original problem has been fixed, and this is a separate topic altogether. But i figured if anyone would like to explain this mystery to anyone else who chances upon this thread may wish to do so.

Comment: You are not including rails_helper in your spec file. And is FactoryBot.create(:user) inside a `it` block?

Comment: It is recommended to use `sequence` for unique field when creating record with `FactoryBot`. You can find cheatsheet [here at devhints.io](https://devhints.io/factory_bot)

Comment: @SujanAdiga i didn't include the `require "rails_helper"` but its in my spec files. My `FactoryBot.create` is in a `before do` block.

Comment: @yeuem1vannam I figure that if i use sequence for the Email, that should resolve my problem since unique emails would be created. But would that be "sweeping the problem under the carpet"? Meaning to say, is my test DB wiping before every run of RSpec?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your full spec files would help. If you are running the specs as you've written - creating a user outside of an example group or a before block - that will cause records to be written outside of the cleaning strategy scope and can cause data to remain across examples. Your DBcleaner config looks to be set up fine otherwise.

`rake db:test:prepare` is the correct way to clean out your test db but shouldn't need to be ran often unless you have migration changes. You can jump into a rails console within the test environment `rails c test` and look around to see if there are any records left behind.

As a side note you can flip `config.use_transactional_fixtures` from `false` to `true` and remove DBcleaner altogether from your app. Just make sure there is no residual data in your database before going this route.

Comment: My creation was done in a `before do` block. The problems were due to Devise requiring unique emails. My problem was solved by using `sequence` for creating the emails in my FactoryBot. I've updated my answer to explain my uncertainties. With regards to `config.use_transactional_fixtures`, it use to be `true` before running into this problem which prompted me to use `DatabaseCleaner`

Comment: Sequences are kind of dodging the problem like you suggested before. Do you have any other factories you're using where a user is created by association? [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is a useful tool that will let you jump into your tests at various points to poke around and see what the state of your database or objects are in. You can also go back into console and manually run your factories to see what they are creating.

Comment: I've actually updated my answer after using sequences. It definitely seems like DatabaseCleaner was working fine. I've even printed my User.email just to take a look at their sequencing in an attempt to figure out whats going on under the hood. But i dont understand rspec well enough to do so. Running the individual spec files should have yielded a sequence of 1 no? But mine was being funky. I'll definitely checkout pry though.

Comment: Ya, they should be starting at 1. Without seeing your app it's hard to tell where specifically the other users are being created, but I would say look in your before hooks or factories for any that are creating more users implicitly. Something else is creating additional ones.